# Why do we sometimes get HTML placeholder values as form submits values?

Tags: html, forms, placeholder

We have a HTML form with some placeholders, such as

```
<input name="position" type="text" maxlength="30" value="" 
  id="position" class="inputLarge" placeholder="(Bsp:Procurement 
  Manager)" size="60" style="ime-mode: active;">
```

Sometimes we record form submits in our database where the fields are just filled with the placeholder text.

When I test that in Chrome, I can not spot this problem - the form properties are empty.

How can that be?

Is it a malfunction of a browser?

Is it some SPAM bot?

Did anybody else experience such behavior?

Comment: You mean to say `placeholder` value is confused for `value`'s value?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes exactly ... but I was not able to reproduce

Answer (score 2):

Remove this: `style="ime-mode: active;"` it's an extension property that causes problems on how data is handled. It only *works* with Firefox and IE which would explain why Chrome s the only browser you have observed working correctly. See this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ime-mode) for details.

Comment: Interesting. Is this a known bug? Did not find a bug report about it. The article you linked says just "it's problematic"

Comment: Yeah, *"problematic"* doesn't pay the bill, right? Plus, there's no mention of it being deprecated or obsolete. Unless you or your users correspond to Asia frequently **and** within a private network environment, you should remove it probably. Just curious, have you tested the inputs without the property?

Comment: Did not test it yet, but I will. The problem is, that I can not repro it myself, I just see the inputs *sometimes* in the database. Will accept, as soon as those are not coming in anymore :)